# How to identify inlinehint llvm functions?

Tags: function, llvm

I need to make a method that returns only the name of the functions that are inlinehint. In the example below, I hope to return: @_ZN16multiplicador16bD2Ev

Example:

```
define linkonce_odr void @_ZN16multiplicador16bD2Ev(%struct.multiplicador16b* %this) unnamed_addr uwtable inlinehint align 2 {

define linkonce_odr void @_ZThn40_N16multiplicador16bD1Ev(%struct.multiplicador16b* %this) unnamed_addr uwtable align 2 {
```

What is the best way to identify inlinehint functions?

Answer (score 0):

inlinehint is a function attribute. So, you need to iterate over all Function's of a Module, check for the presence of attribute and grab the name of the matched ones.

Answer (score 0):

You can return the function name by reading the `CallInst` inside the block.